# HttpContext null from injected IHttpContextAccessor

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core

I have an authorization handler that I am injecting a custom personService into. I have wired up both the handler and the personService through the default DI. The person service IhttpContextAccessor works fine elsewhere in my application, but when it is called from the authorization handler, httpcontext is always null.

Here is the AuthHandler:

```
     public class NoChildrenRequirement : AuthorizationHandler<NoChildrenRequirement>, IAuthorizationRequirement
{
    private readonly IPersonService _personService;

    public NoChildrenRequirement(IPersonService personService)
    {
        _personService = personService;
    }

    protected override void Handle(AuthorizationContext context, NoChildrenRequirement requirement)
    {
        var user = context.User;
        var identity = user.Identity;
        var isAuthenticated = identity.IsAuthenticated;

        var currentPerson = _personService.CurrentPerson();

        if (isAuthenticated && currentPerson != null && !currentPerson.IsAChild)
        {
            context.Succeed(requirement);
            return;
        }
        context.Fail();
    }
}
```

Here is where I wire it up in startup:

```
     services.AddTransient<NoChildrenRequirement>();
        services.Configure<AuthorizationOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("NoChildren", policy => policy.Requirements.Add(
                services.BuildServiceProvider().GetRequiredService<NoChildrenRequirement>()));
        });
```

Here is the start of the personservice:

```
     public class PersonService : IPersonService
{
    private readonly IPersonRepository _repository;
    private readonly IMemoryCache _memoryCache;
    private readonly IConfigService _configService;
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _context;
    private readonly IResourceService _resourceService;
    private readonly string _cacheKey = "Person_";

    public PersonService(IPersonRepository repository, IMemoryCache memoryCache, 
        IConfigService configService, IHttpContextAccessor context, 
        IResourceService resourceService)
    {
        _repository = repository;
        _memoryCache = memoryCache;
        _configService = configService;
        _context = context;
        _resourceService = resourceService;
    }
```

Here is where I wire up person service in startup:

```
    services.AddTransient<IPersonService, PersonService>();
```

If I access : IHttpContextAccessor _context; in person service anywhere else in the application, it works, when I call personservice from the authhandler, all of the other dependencies wire up correctly and even the concrete HttpContextAccessor value is not null, but HttpContext within HttpContextAccessor is null. Any ideas?

Comment: I also tried this with an ActionFilter and it fails the same way. Everything else seems to wire up and work properly.

Comment: RC1 - I do not see RC2 out there - v1.0.0-rc1-final

Comment: I have tried everything that I can think of and still no dice.

Comment: The next thing you should do is file a bug on aspnet/Home and put a repo project on github that shows the issue.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the help.

Comment: I Have the same issue did you ever get it fixed?

Comment: It is answered here: https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/1257